# JQuery Toggle animation interfering with CSS height transition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JQuery function to toggle a Div with ( toggle(200) ) so there is a small sliding animation.

However I have another function that will add a class to this div, which change the height of the div with a 0.3s transition.

```
#navbar {
    height: 270px;
    transition: height 0.3s ease-out;
}

#navbar.change-size {
    height: 430px !important;
}
```

My problem is that the transition isn't just applying to the height (which was the intended purpose) but it also applies to the first JQuery function toggling when the div slides in.

My question is how can I set up my css so the height transition effect only applies to `.change-size` height ?

PS: I didn't add my JQuery toggle code as I believe it is not relevant. The JQuery sliding animation is probably tweaking the div's height/width to create the sliding effect, therefore being influenced by the transition I set up.

Please let me know if I'm unclear. Thank you !

Comment: So why not add the transition to the class `.change-size` instead? You will remove the class with a setTimeout or once the animation is complete (no idea when are you adding/removing the class)?

Comment: The problem with putting the transition on on the `.change-size` is that there is no animation on the way back when the class is removed :( I was thinking one alternative would be to create an animation that simply change the size of the element but I don't know if this is possible. This way insteaf of writting `transition: height 0.3s` I would write it `transition: animation-name 0.3s` so it wouldn't interfer with the JQuery sliding animation.

Comment: Why are you asking a question that clearly needs a [mcve]? You are animating elements and mentioning another animation but consider it irrelevant? So just letting you you are very unclear.

Comment: @eloism if you remove the class the correct way it will have an animation on the way back. I mentioned how already.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

[little fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ga6vm031/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #navbar {
            height: 270px;
            -ms-transition: all .3s ease-out; /*IE*/
            -moz-transition: all .3s ease-out; /*firefox*/
            -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-out;/*safari and chrome*/
            -o-transition: all .3s ease-out; /*opera*/
            background-color: #999;
        }

        #navbar.change-size {
            height: 430px;
        }
        </style>

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="navbar">
            Hello
        </div>

        <button id="toggle">.change-size</button>
        <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#toggle").on("click", function(){
                $("#navbar").addClass("change-size");
            })
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```